# View Images From Url and Place in ImageView when User selects

Tags: android, image, url, imageview

Am develop the Frame application. For that i want to display images(frames) from url. the url has more than 50 images. For that i use gridview but it lacks some points such as,

1.It speeds very slow to load images.

2.We declare the name and size of the images at code time so that we dont add images to the url after publishing the applicaton.

I need solution for these asap. Please anyone give me suggestion.

Comment: please tell me what you have done?

Comment: Am using gridview. but need solution instead of that. Display images from url and pick that one and fix it in imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below link of lazy loading listview, this will help you.

[Lazy Loading ListView](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Use Above link Code and Add another activity and another layout for display selected image, if u have any issue than tell me, i will put full code here.

Comment: Hi dipak, I go through the lazy list. But cant get the code for changing the size of the image in the list. Would you know that?

Comment: please see into item.xml, and change the size of imageview 50dip to 100dip or more.

Answer (score 0):

**1.It speeds very slow to load images.**

> It will depend on You bandwidth and device Cache.

**2. We declare the name and size of the images at code time so that we dont add images to the url after publishing the application.**

You can have predefine URL so at code time you can append the image name to url.and once you have URL ready using AsyncTask download images one by one \

**The below snippets will help you.**

**DownloadHelper.java**

```
public interface DownloadHelper
{
    public void OnSucess(Bitmap bitmap);
    public void OnFailure(String response);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class GalleryExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DownloadHelper downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper()
        {
            @Override
            public void OnSucess(Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void OnFailure(String response)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        new MyTask(this,downloadHelper).execute("image url");
    }
```

**MyTask.java**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object>
{
    private Context context;
    private DownloadHelper downloadHelper;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    public DownloadTask(Context context,DownloadHelper downloadHelper)
    {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setMessage("Fetching Data!!");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
        {
            downloadHelper.OnSucess((Bitmap)result);
        } 
        else
        {
            downloadHelper.OnFailure("Error in Downloading Data!!");
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i need to select the image in url by user. The url has more images the user selects the one and that image i need to  display in imageview.